# Identifying hex value of keystrokes

Tags: audio, hex, keyboard-events, keystroke

I need some guidance on how to write a Perl, VBScript or JavaScript code to display the hex value of a key stroke. I need this mainly for multimedia keys in keyboard like mute, volume up, volume down, etc.

Comment: We aren't here to write code for you, what have you tried? Attempt something and if it doesn't work, then ask for help.

Comment: Actually I need to use SendKeys method of vbscript to send mute , volume up and volume down keys. For that I need to find the hex value. 'Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))' will mute the volume. Similarly I need hex code for increase and decrease volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily somebody already wrote it: See
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/javascriptkey2.shtml